# JavaFX TableView get row from button cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Referring to question [JavaFX TableView custom cell rendering split menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577364/), i'm able to render split menu button in every row. I've updated my code as suggested by [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) and in the answer by [Keyur Bhanderi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5906488/keyur-bhanderi).
The question is about get value of the row where split menu is located without selecting row before click.

**Update: Added images to view output**

The images below show the output, every button i click.

[image: Row selected click frist action button]

[image: Row selected click second action button]

**Updated SplitMenuCellFactory.java**

```
package com.example.splimenubtn;

import java.util.List;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SplitMenuCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {

 private List<MenuItemFactory<T>> menuItems;

 public SplitMenuCellFactory() {}

 public SplitMenuCellFactory(List<MenuItemFactory<T>> items) {
  menuItems = items;
 }

 @Override
 public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> param) {
  return new TableCell<S, T>() {
   @Override
   public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
     setGraphic(null);
     setText(null);
    } else {
     setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
     if (getTableRow() != null) {
      setGraphic(new SplitMenuButtonFactory<>(menuItems, getTableRow().getIndex()).buildButton());
     }
    }
   }
  };
 }
}
```

**Update, adding missing class**

**SplitMenuButtonFactory.java**

```
package com.example.splimenubtn;

 import java.util.List;
 import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
 import javafx.scene.control.SplitMenuButton;

 public class SplitMenuButtonFactory<T> {

  private List<MenuItemFactory<T>> menuItems;
  private int rIndex = 0;

  public SplitMenuButtonFactory(List<MenuItemFactory<T>> items) {
   menuItems = items;
  }

  public SplitMenuButtonFactory(List<MenuItemFactory<T>> items, int rI) {
   menuItems = items;
   rIndex = rI;
  }

  public SplitMenuButton buildButton() {
   SplitMenuButton menuBtn = new SplitMenuButton();
   // menuBtn.getItems().addAll(menuItems);
   for (MenuItemFactory<?> mIF : menuItems) {
    MenuItem btn = mIF.setRowIndex(rIndex).buildMenuItem();
     if (mIF.isDefault()) {
     menuBtn.setText(btn.getText());
     menuBtn.setOnAction(btn.getOnAction());
    }
    menuBtn.getItems().add(btn);
   }
  return menuBtn;
 }
}
```

**MenuItemsFactory.java**

```
package com.example.splimenubtn;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class MenuItemFactory<S> {

 private MenuItemActions itemType;
 private String itemLbl;
 private TableView<S> table;
 private boolean defaultAction;
 private int rIndex = 0;

 public MenuItemFactory(MenuItemActions itemType, String itemLabel, boolean dA) {
  this.itemType = itemType;
  itemLbl = itemLabel;
  defaultAction = dA;
 }

 public MenuItemFactory(MenuItemActions itemType, String itemLabel, TableView<S> t, boolean dA) {
  this.itemType = itemType;
  itemLbl = itemLabel;
  defaultAction = dA;
  table = t;
 }

 public MenuItemFactory<S> setDataList(TableView<S> t) {
  table = t;
  return this;
 }

 public boolean isDefault() {
  return defaultAction;
 }

 public MenuItemFactory<S> setRowIndex(int rI) {
  rIndex = rI;
  return this;
 }

 public MenuItem buildMenuItem() {
  MenuItem mI = new MenuItem();
  switch (itemType) {
   case DETAILS:
    mI.setText(itemLbl);
    mI.setOnAction(handleDetails());
   break;
  case EDIT:
    mI.setText(itemLbl);
    mI.setOnAction(handleEdit());
   break;
   case DELETE:
    mI.setText(itemLbl);
    mI.setOnAction(handleDelete());
   break;
   default:
   break;
  }
  return mI;
 }

 private EventHandler<ActionEvent> handleDetails() {
  return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent aE) {
    System.out.println("*** DETAIL REQUEST ***");
   }
  };
 }

 private EventHandler<ActionEvent> handleEdit() {
  return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent aE) {
    System.out.println("*** EDIT REQUESTED ***");
    table.getSelectionModel().select(rIndex);
    System.out.println("*** " + table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + " ***");
   }
  };
 }

 private EventHandler<ActionEvent> handleDelete() {
  return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent aE) {
    System.out.println("*** DELETE REQUESTED ***");
    System.out.println("*** " + table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString() + " ***");
   }
  };
 }
}
```

But when i click on the button, i'm getting always last value.

How can i get the object in the row where button is?

Any help or suggestion that point me to right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `TableCell` to retrieve the value in the `onAction` event handler (or whatever you use in the product of the `SplitMenuButtonFactory` you're not showing to us).

#### Simplified example

```
public static SplitMenuButton createSplitMenuButton(final TableCell cell) {
    SplitMenuButton result = new SplitMenuButton();

    result.setOnAction(evt -> {
        TableRow row = cell.getTableRow();
        System.out.println("row item: " +row.getItem());
    });

    return result;
}
```

Furthermore it's better to reuse the `SplitMenuButton` in the cell and updating it instead of recerating it every time the cell item changes.

```
@Override
public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> param) {
    return new TableCell<S, T>() {

        private final SplitMenuButton button = createSplitMenuButton(this);

        {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                updateMenuButton(button, item); // placeholder for updating the button according to the new item

                setGraphic(button);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: you can view the SplitMenuButtonFactory in the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577364/